# При скролле сильно тормозит таблица или какие другим способом можно сделать круглую ImageView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Доброе время суток всем, у меня уже был похожий вопрос, но тут другое, в общем тормозит таблица при скролле, вот код:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCell *cell = [[self tableView] dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    Mapping *mapping = [[self arrayData] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [[cell myTextLabel] setText:[mapping name]];
    [[cell myDetailTextLabel] setText:[mapping last_name]];
    [[cell myImageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[mapping imageData]]];

//Делаю круглую myImageView
    [self.myImageView.layer setCornerRadius:self.myImageView.frame.size.width / 2];
    [self.myImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];

    return cell;
}
```

Было замеченно, что тормоза из-за этих строк, которые делают myImageView круглой, но почему так, каим другим способом можно сделать круглую myImageView?

Вот код, как я делаю круглую..

```
[self.myImageView.layer setCornerRadius:self.myImageView.frame.size.width / 2];
[self.myImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Что не так в этих строках?

Comment: В другой поток вынести эти действия

Answer (score 1):

попробуй в фоне менять радиус

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Код, который должен выполнится в фоне

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Код, который выполнится в главном потоке
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучшее решение это использовать фон с закруглениями. Используйте 9-patсh или стандартный `resizableImageWithCapInsets`